# Find multivariate pdf of a multivariate function

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Consider the following function:

$Y(t) = X_1 \exp{(-X_2 t)}$

where the parameters $X_1, X_2$ are random variables and $t$ is the time.

How to find the analytical expression of the probability density function of the function $Y(t)$?

Comment: Using just the definition, it's straightforward to write down an expression for the PDF--but whether you consider that "analytical," or even useful, is another matter. If you want more than such a generality, could you indicate what the distribution function of $(X_1, X_2)$ is?

Comment: In a first time, we can suppose that random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ follow normal distributions:

$X_1 \sim  \mathcal{N}(m_1,\sigma_1)$,
$X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(m_2,\sigma_2)$

Comment: Some closely related posts which might also be helpful can be found by searching our site for [normal lognormal product](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+lognormal+product).